# Assigning a role to an existing user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

Good day everyone,

I am having some trouble assigning a role to an existing user in MVC5, which will be done by an Admin from a view only accessible by an Admin Thus far I have created a role upon startup and assigned it to a SuperUser who will thereafter have the right to grant the role of an Admin to other specific users.

```
        private void createRolesAndDefaultUser()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db));
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));

        //Creation of "Admin" role and Default Admin
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
        {
            //Create "Admin" role
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "Admin";
            roleManager.Create(role);

            //Create SuperUser/DefaultAdmin
            var User = new ApplicationUser();
            User.UserName = "superUser@email.com";
            User.Email = "superUser@email.com";
            string Password = "Password01!";

            var superUser = UserManager.Create(User, Password);

            //Assign role to superUser
            if (superUser.Succeeded)
            {
                var res = UserManager.AddToRole(User.Id, "Admin");
            }
        }
    }
```

I have seen many articles online which allow the assigning of roles upon registration. Since I would not want users picking their own roles, it is up to the SuperUser to assign the role of an Admin to existing users.

The problem I am having is how do I enable the assigning of roles to users which can only be done by the SuperUser?

Answer (score 0):

```
var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
            UserManager.AddToRole(UserManager.FindByName(temp).Id, "Admin");
```

temp stores the UserName of the user that will be granted an admin right